# Finding midpoint given coordinates of two locations

Tags: python, coordinates, gis

(New-ish Python user here)

I'm utilizing the [nvector](https://pypi.org/project/nvector/) module to make some geodetic calculations based on the WGS-84 ellipsoid. I believe my code is pretty much complete, but the midpoint values for longitude and latitude are not printing out when I run it. Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this issue?

```
#points = nv.Geopoint(latitude=[-83.9207, 10.7522], longitude=[35.9606, 59.9139],
#                               degrees=True)
import nvector as nv

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, lat, lon):
        self.lat=lat
        self.lon=lon

def findGeogMidpoint(vert1, vert2):
    wgs84=nv.FrameE(name='wgs84')
    n_EB_E_t0 = wgs84.GeoPoint(-83.9207, 35.9606, degrees=True).to_nvector()
    n_EB_E_t1 = wgs84.GeoPoint(10.7522, 59.9139, degrees=True).to_nvector()
    path = nv.GeoPath(n_EB_E_t0, n_EB_E_t1)
    halfway=0.5
    g_EB_E_ti = path.interpolate(halfway).to_geo_point()
    lat_ti, lon_ti = g_EB_E_ti.latitude_deg, g_EB_E_ti.longitude_deg
    return Vertex(float(lat_ti), float(lon_ti))
```

Comment: well you just defined some functions, you never call anything

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your function is not printing because you simply have not told python to print the results.

```
return Vertex(float(lat_ti), float(lon_ti))
```

only *passes* the results, but does not print them.

Use this:

```
print(findGeogMidpoint(vert1, vert2))
```